# NFS export for non-root users

Tags: ubuntu, centos, permissions, nfs, export

I need non-root users to be able to export folders over NFS on a shared system.
There are a lot of users, several hundred, who may potentially log into the system.  All of them should be able to export certain stuff in their home folder via NFS.

Is there an application that could help with that?
Something that would accept non-root user requests to modify /etc/exports, maybe do some security checks, notify nfsd that new share is available or was removed.

I guess, users are trusted enough, so that it might be possible to allow access to exportfs via sudo.  That would also take care of races.
But exportfs does not update /etc/exports, so in case of the reboot all the exports will be gone.

Are there any other solutions?

Exporting via a different protocol might also be an option.
I just need to be able to mount those exports on another Ubuntu/CentOS system.
Exporting is happening on CentOS.

Comment: You can create a s script that will update /etc/exports and call exportall. Then you can call the script with sudo.